# How can I fix a SqlException incorrect syntax error in my code?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

This is code that references a SQL Server database to retrieve to information to be put into a `DataGridView`.

I get an error:

> SqlException [incorrect syntax]

Code:

```
private void DisplayData()
{
    adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT geoCode, cancer2004" +
                               "FROM Regional_Intel$" +
                               "WHERE geoCode LIKE '" + txtDMA.Text + "'", con);
    // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dma", txtDMA.Text);

    dt = new DataTable();
    adapt.Fill(dt);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: use space before each " and its better use '%' after like like '%"+ txtDMA.Text + "%'" because its not difference between  LIKE '" + txtDMA.Text + "'" and   ='" + txtDMA.Text + "'"

Comment: @Justin, Is any update? If your question has been solved , you can click '✔' to mark the appropriate reply as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add spaces in your SQL string.  Also, very bad idea to use string concatenation.

Add spaces like this:

```
{
    adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("Select geoCode, cancer2004 " +
        "FROM Regional_Intel$ " +
        "where geoCode LIKE '" + txtDMA.Text + "'", con);
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dma", txtDMA.Text);
    dt = new DataTable();
    adapt.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Use parameters like this:

```
{
    adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("Select geoCode, cancer2004 " +
        "FROM Regional_Intel$ " +
        "where geoCode LIKE @dma", con);
    adapt.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@dma", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtDMA.Text;
    dt = new DataTable();
    adapt.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Separate out your SQL string:

```
{
   var query = @"
SELECT geoCode, cancer2004
FROM Regional_Intel$
WHERE geoCode LIKE @dma";
    adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    adapt.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@dma", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtDMA.Text;
    dt = new DataTable();
    adapt.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: I'm not covering it here, but things that implement IDisposable should be disposed when you are done with them.  SqlDataAdapter and DataTable both implement IDisposable.  DataTable is a bit of a special case, but there are better answers about that out there.